# Do unclaimed weapons from the 'Shadow Soldiers' in the Depths change after every Blood Moon?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I have been trying to find a pristine Zora Spear from the Depths, but every 'Shadow Soldier' that I find carrying a spear beneath the Zora's Domain doesn't have it. I tried saving and reloading from a far-away distance, but when I come close, it doesn't refresh or change.

This brings me to my question... if I don't claim any of those spears, would they remain as-is on the next Blood Moon? Or do I have to get them so they could 'refresh' by the next Blood Moon?

Comment: Just for information if you are looking for a pristine Zora spear, the Mipha amiibo drop it (with a pretty high probability).

Comment: Yeah, I actually have received it from the Amiibo. But I'm looking for the alternative in the Depths should it break, didn't get it in the Amiibo, as well as mapping purposes for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pick it up at least once to make the Shadow soldier reroll it the next Blood Moon, or it will remain stuck with the "basic" default weapon.

Then wait for the first Blood Moon, that will reroll the pristine weapons you picked/removed. What actually "freezes" the weapon is if you walk too close and make the Shadow soldier appear, that rerolls the weapon and make it stay the same until you pick it up again.

This means you can easily save-scum a bit far away (when the Shadow soldier is not yet visible) and hope for the weapon you are looking for to spawn.

It's worth noting that the effect applied is decided only once you pick the weapon up, not when the weapon is generated. This means that you can also save-scum for the effect when close to the pedestal.

Answer (score 6):

> If I don't claim any of those spears, would they remain as-is on the next Blood Moon?

From my testing, weapons that the Shadow Soldiers hold will respawn after a Blood Moon. In terms of the weapon changing, it depends which Shadow Soldier you go to. For instance [this Shadow Solider](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/tears-of-the-kingdom-interactive-map/?l=Depths&z=5&x=-245&y=3700&m=Pristine%20Weapon%282h%29%28Zora%20Longsword%29) from the object map will always hold a Pristine Zora Longsword.

Also from the object map, it seems [this Shadow Solider](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/tears-of-the-kingdom-interactive-map/?l=Depths&z=6&x=-665&y=2363&m=Pristine%20Weapon%28Spear%29%28Zora%20Spear%29) (Coordinates 2363-0665-0562) is the only one that will hold a Pristine Zora Spear but it can also hold a Pristine Travelers Spear.

From my testing, not collecting this spear and triggering a Blood Moon, this specific Shadow Solider still held the travelers spear so I would say it is safe to say if you collect the weapon the Blood Moon will reroll which weapon the Shadow Solider will hold (again, only the Shadow Soldiers that can hold multiple items).

Comment: But is collecting the weapon the only way to make it reroll? If it happens to hold a traveler's sword, will it always be a traveler's sword until I pick it up and the next blood moon happens? I think you answered a different question entirely. (will a weapon respawn after a blood moon)

Comment: @JeffMercado as I wrote in my answer: from my testing, not collecting the spear and triggering a Blood Moon that specific Shadow Solider still held the travelers spear (instead of spawning the Zora Spear) so I would say it is safe to say if you collect the weapon the Blood Moon will reroll which weapon that Shadow Solider will hold.

Comment: @Cenzo Safe to say it will reroll if you **do** pick it up, but the OP's question was explicitly whether it would reroll if you **don't** pick it up. Your one datapoint does little to establish whether it wasn't rerolled or it just happened to roll the same thing again, so it doesn't answer that question.